# ISO Plugin: Audit Trail with Diff of Content Changes

Tags: logging

I have tried the mainstream auditing plugins out there and they all fall short of giving me the most critical feature: A diff view of a theme file that was edited.

I've tried WP Activity Log (premium) which logs that changes were made to the files I am interested in but not WHAT was changed within them.

Does anyone know if such a plugin exists?

Comment: I can't vote for closure because there's a bounty attached, but please note that "in search of plugin" type question are [off topic](/help/on-topic) here. If you'd like to know more, there's [some discussion on Meta](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations).

Answer (score 0):

**Full disclosure, I'm the founder and author of the Shield Security plugin.**

Yes, this feature is available in the [Shield Security PRO plugin](https://getshieldsecurity.com/). It is only available for plugins and themes that are installed from WordPress.org.  This is because in order to create a diff, you need access to the original file contents and we don't have access to the original files for premium plugins/themes.

ShieldPRO will use the original file contents for WordPress.org core, plugins and themes and present you with a visual "diff", wherever this is possible.

Here's a screenshot I made earlier where I edited the style file for Theme 2023 by removing a line (red, on the left) and adding a line (green, on the right):

[image]

It's also worth nothing the we provide the functionality to view the diff of changes made to your `wp-config.php`, `.htaccess` files, but based on quite a different mechanism. These files are completely unique to the website and so there is never going to be an original file to diff with. So the plugin will create a copy of the file (encrypted) which is then compared against the current contents of the file on every page load.  When it changes, you can again get [a full diff of the file](https://getshieldsecurity.com/blog/shieldpro-feature-file-locker/).

Full disclosure, I'm the founder and author of the Shield Security plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - It looks like a potential option! One question:
"ShieldPRO will use the original file contents for WordPress.org core, plugins and themes and present you with a visual "diff", wherever this is possible."
If read strictly, does the diff only show differences from the original only, or from a previous version local to the site? If the latter is true then does it also handle a full replacement of the file (if uploaded/replaced by FTP)?

Comment: The diff is only shown against the original file. Shield doesn't store "copies" of files, that's too costly, especially for large sites with lots of plugins. Where ShieldPRO can access an original file distributed for a given version of a plugin/theme/WordPress, it'll diff against that. So if you have a file, modify it, then modify again, it'll diff against the original. Where the original is available, there's a built-in function within Shield to replace file contents with originals. Shield can do this automatically or you can click a button manually to do it (if file permissions allow).

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying this! While a cool feature to prevent tampering with original files, this doesn't quite suit the my needs. The lack of this feature is unsurprising with github integration existing.

Comment: In what way does it not meet your needs? And what github integration are you referring to?

Comment: Very strange, your question stated: "A diff view of a theme file that was edited". I provided that, you said it didn't meet your needs - I'd love to know why it doesn't meet your needs, could you elaborate, please?  Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to show a diff of what was previously there (versus what was originally there).

Comment: You won't find that anywhere unless you're running version control (Git, SVN). It's otherwise impossible to track that with a simple WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in [WP Admin Audit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-admin-audit) (even in the free version I believe).

It captures changes done through the Theme and/or Plugin editor.

Example:
[image: WordPress plugin file was edited in the plugin editor, WP Admin Audit showing the changes in the WordPress event log]

Comment: I would be inclined to award the bounty; however, I am getting an error when attempting to view a theme-file edit log (where the diff is shown) on both a local copy and on a shared WP host:   
Warning: require_once(/... wp-content/plugins/wp-admin-audit/classes/Lib/PHP-FineDiff-multibyte/GorHill/FineDiff/FineDiffHtml.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /dmcm/git/wpstandalone/wp-content/plugins/wp-admin-audit/classes/Views/Layouts/FileEvent.php on line 52

and, FineDiffHtml.php on ... /wp-content/plugins/wp-admin-audit/classes/Views/Layouts/FileEvent.php on line 52